# Total Sample Space Count - Permutation or Combination?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations

Consider the scenario that you have 50 balls and let an experiment be that 5 balls are randomly selected. How can I calculate the total number of sample points (the elements in the sample space)?

Should I use 50C5 (50 choose 5) or should I do 50P5 (50 permute 5)? I've mostly seen "combination" being used but I can't understand the essence of it.

For the first ball, we have 50 options, and for the next we have 49 ways, for the next we have 48 ways to choose a ball and so on. From the fundamental rule of counting, it should be 50x49x48x47x46 (which is 50P5).

Comment: You can do either, provided you are consistent.  If you use combinations to count the number of events in the sample space, you must also use combinations to count the number of favorable cases.  If you instead use permutations to count the number of events in the sample space, you must also use permutations to count the number of favorable cases.

Comment: Well, the question is: does the order matter? Is
$$
\{ \text{blue ball, yellow ball, red ball} \}
$$
considered the same sample as
$$
\{ \text{blue ball, red ball, yellow ball} \}
$$ ?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig would the answer be the same regardless of using permutations or combinations? Or are you saying it depends on what we're trying to find, how our experiment is designed?

Comment: @ParkerQueen The answer on what question?.. Mostly "yes" if it concerns probability (certainly if no order of the selecting of the balls is involved) but "no" if it concerns counting.

Comment: Since you used the phrase sample space, I am assuming that you are interested in calculating a probability, in which case the answer would be the same regardless of whether you use permutations or combinations.  That said, if the problem can be done with combinations, it tends to reduce computation.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig thanks a bunch. that cleared my doubts.

Comment: @drhab yes, I was talking about probability. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give it an analogy (or a real life example): You're a coach of an NBA team with 50 players. You need to choose 5 players to play tonight. In how many ways can you form a team of 5?

If you choose: A,B,C,D & E to play it's identical to choosing E,D,C,B & A. Point is: **it doesn't matter which one comes first or last** - you just need 5 players.

For this - you use **C**ombination! - mind the 5! that eliminates all same combo.
$$\binom{50}{5} = \frac{50!}{45!5!} $$

However, in permutation the order is important. Back to the NBA: in how many ways can you choose 5 players from a poll of 50 players where the first player is considered MVP the second player is vice-MVP and so forth? Answer: 50x49x48x47x46

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of demonstrating N. F.'s point in the comments, let's suppose the balls are labelled 1 through 50 and a "success" is choosing balls 1 through 5.

If you choose the balls one at a time (so that they can be distinguished by their order), then the probability of a success is
$$
\frac{5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1}{50 \cdot 49 \cdot 48 \cdot 47 \cdot 46} = \frac{1}{2118760}.
$$

If you choose the balls five at a time (so that they cannot be distinguished by their order), then the probability of a success is
$$
\frac{5 C 5}{50 C 5} = \frac{1}{2118760}.
$$

As long as you are consistent in your application of order in both the numerator and the denominator, you get the same probability. (This is actually quite a useful observation, as many probability calculations are much simpler if you suppose that order matters.)